# error 1119 and 1120

Tags: flash, getter

I'm trying to use a getter but after boiling the code down to the simplest thing I can think of I still end up with the same errors.  Here is the code for error 1119

Main:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }
        public function init():void
        {
            if (Player.value == 23)
            {
                trace("if statment")
            }
            trace(Player.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Player:

```
package
{
    public class Player
    {
        private var _numberOfKeys:uint;

        public function Player()
        {
            _numberOfKeys = 23;
        }
        public function get value():uint
        {
            return _numberOfKeys;
        }
    }
}
```

and I get the error on both lines trying to use the get function, if I change the Player get value function to "public static function" it reads the value of _numberOfKeys and says it's undefined but if I hard code a number it passes it to the Main class with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand the problem, you'll need to understand the difference between a class and an instance of a class.
Static function are accessible from the Class itself, which non static functions can only be accessed after an object is initiated.

To fix the first situation you'll need to write something like :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }
        public function init():void
        {
            var instance:Player = new Player();
            if (instance.value == 23)
            {
                trace("if statment")
            }
            trace(Player.value);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why you get the errors you get when you change the value function to static is because the _numberOfKeys isn't static.

Comment: Thank you, I have been fighting with this for days and couldn't find a simple explanation.  Just to make it clear in my mind.  If I use addChild() to put movie clips on stage then whatever variable I us for the movie clip will also hold the class that their tied to?  If I just use a separate class to hold variables then I need to create a variable in the Main class to access the other class through?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend your `Main` class to contain an instance of `Player`, then instantiate a player from main's `init()`:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var player:Player;

        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }
        public function init():void
        {
            player = new Player();
            trace(player.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you intend for Player's `value` property to be static, then it must be able to reference `_numberOfKeys` statically initialized, such as:

```
package
{
    public class Player
    {
        private static var _numberOfKeys:uint = 23;

        public static function get value():uint
        {
            return _numberOfKeys;
        }
    }
}
```